# How to fetch element with 'name' attribute in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing my react app with react testing library and jest.

And I want to know how to fetch element with 'name' attribute in react-testing-library.

For example, in the following page, is it possible to fetch this element with "userName"?

```html
<input type="text" name="userName" />
```

Or should I set `data-testId` into the element and use `getByTestId` method?

```js
return (
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="userName" />
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 40):

You can use the returned [`container`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#container). The `container` is a DOM node and supports the [`querySelector` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which accepts a CSS selector to find an element. Same approach as in [this more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54250578/8068625).

For example:

```
const { container } = render(<MyComponent />);
const inputEl = container.querySelector(`input[name="userName"]`);
```

Answer (score 28):

The general recommended way to find elements in the DOM is taking an
approach that resembles the way application is used.

In this particular example `name` attribute will not be recognised as pointed out by @ggorlen.

As a fallback for the text input you could either rely on `getByLabelText` (assuming you have added a label with `htmlFor`), or you could add `aria-label` to your text input:

```
<input type="text" aria-label="userName" />
```

and then use:

```
screen.getByRole("textbox", {name: /userName/i});
```

The "problem" with `data-testid` is you have to add it specifically for your tests, instead of relying on more natural `findByRole`, `findByPlaceholderText`, `findByLabelText`.

`getByTestId` should be your last resort.

As a follow up I recommend using Testing Playground browser extension, which generates RTL queries for elements, in a similar fashion to find element in browser devTools.

Also, when troubled with searching by name (or other attributes), try to investigate on accessibility features of given element/component to figure precisely how to search for it.

Comment: There may be some confusion about `name` here. It's the aria accessible name, not the `name="userName"` attribute. See [What is the name option in react-testing-library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69198906/what-is-the-name-option-in-react-testing-library/69227320#69227320).

Comment: I [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74817172/6243352) with an example showing that this approach `{name: /userName/i}` doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I updated my answer, so no misinformed code snippet is here for future readers. I also tagged you, so you are credited.

Comment: this work for me, 
after adding `aria-label="somekey"` on in input and query using `getByRole` 

Example: `getByRole("textbox", { name: /somekey/i })`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of [resorting to the native DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69887027/6243352), in certain situations you can select the element by role (or, less ideally, by test id), then assert that the attribute in question exists, in lieu of an all-in-one `getBy` call:

```js
expect(screen.getByRole("textbox")).toHaveAttribute("name", "userName");
```

Unfortunately,

```js
screen.getByRole("textbox", {name: "userName"});
```

doesn't work as it seems like it should. See [What is the name option in react-testing-library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69198906/what-is-the-name-option-in-react-testing-library/69227320#69227320) for an explanation.

Proof:

```js
import React from "react"; // 18.2.0
import {render, screen} from "@testing-library/react"; // 13.4.0
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"; // ^5.16.5

describe("getByRole experiments", () => {
  beforeEach(() => render(<input type="text" name="userName" />));

  it("should work with a plain getByRole", () => {
    expect(screen.getByRole("textbox"))
      .toHaveAttribute("name", "userName"); // OK
  });

  it("will fail specifying {name: /userName/i}", () => {
    screen.getByRole("textbox", {name: /userName/i}); // Fails
  });

  it('will also fail specifying {name: "userName"}', () => {
    screen.getByRole("textbox", {name: "userName"}); // Fails
  });
});
```

Partial output (the `name: "userName"` assertion failure is basically the same):

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "textbox" and name `/userName/i`

Here are the accessible roles:

  textbox:

  Name "":
  <input
    name="userName"
  />

  --------------------------------------------------

Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
<body>
  <div>
    <input
      name="userName"
    />
  </div>
</body>
```

See also [React testing library: how to getByRole on custom role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71850026/react-testing-library-how-to-getbyrole-on-custom-role/74816504#74816504).

Comment: Would it work for `password` field?

Comment: See [dom-testing-library issue #567](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/567) for selecting password fields.