# What is the name option in react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Ever since starting with @testing-library for react, I'm confused by the `name` attribute. It is possible to get the reference of a rendered button e. g. like this:

```
// <button>Button text</button>
screen.getbyRole("button", {name: /button text/gi})
```

In this case name referes to the `textNode` inside of the button. The story around inputs is similar where `name` can refer to e.g. the `id` the `name` or the text content.

I'm currently trying to get the reference of a button that is rendered like this:

```
<button
  aria-label="Close"
  class="css-1dliicy"
  type="button"
  >
  Create new
  <svg>...</svg>
</button>
```

And the button can not be found with the query:

```
const createNewButton = screen.getByRole('button', {
    name: /Create new/gi,
});
```

I clearly don't seem to know what the `name` property means but I can't seem to find docs on it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `name` property refers to the accessible name of the element you're trying to query.

From the [`ByRole` query docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole#api) (third paragraph):

> You can query the returned element(s) by their [accessible name](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/). The
> accessible name is for simple cases equal to e.g. the label of a form
> element, or the text content of a button, or the value of the
> `aria-label` attribute. It can be used to query a specific element if
> multiple elements with the same role are present on the rendered
> content.

---

As [@Moistbobo referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69201561/1870780), since your button has `aria-label="Close"`, then `Close` will be its accessible name.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the first button doesn't have an aria-label, and by default will fallback to using the button content for accessibility.

As the second button has `Close` as an aria-label, the `name` property in this case should be `Close`.

I've written the following tests to demonstrate this.

```js
import {render} from "@testing-library/react";

describe('test', () => {
   it('find by name -> aria-label', () => {
       const {getByRole} = render(<button
           aria-label="Close"
           className="css-1dliicy"
           type="button"
       >
           Create new
       </button>)

       const button = getByRole('button', {name: 'Close'});

       expect(button).toBeTruthy();
   })

    it('find by name -> button content', () => {
        const {getByRole} = render(
            <button>button text</button>
        );

        const button = getByRole("button", {name: /button text/gi});

        expect(button).toBeTruthy();
    })

    it('will throw an error', () => {
        const {getByRole} = render(
            <button>button text</button>
        );

        /** will throw this error:
         * Unable to find an accessible element with the role "button" and name `/button texat/gi`
         *  Here are the accessible roles:
         *
         *  button:
         *
         *  Name "button text":
         */
        const button = getByRole("button", {name: /button texta/gi});

        expect(button).toBeTruthy();
    })
});
```