# How to access an input element of type checkbox and name using react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have HTML code like so:

```
<label class="switch" value="true">
    <input name="source" type="checkbox"/>
</label>
```

How can I access input with name `source`? I have tried using `getByRole` and `name` attribute, but it throws an error that this input has `name=""`.

Below is the tried solution that doesn't work:

```
screen.getByRole('checkbox', { name: 'source' });
```

How can I access this input element in other way?

I have tried to do like so as per solution provided

```
const elem = document.querySelector(
    `input[name="source"]`);
if (elem) {
    userEvent.click(elem);
}
```

This works but if I remove if statement like so

```
const elem = document.querySelector(
    `input[name="source"]`);
userEvent.click(elem);
```

I get an error:

> Argument of type null| element is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'targetelement'. type null is not assignable to type targetelement

Comment: How did you tried? Post your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch element with 'name' attribute in react-testing-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986454/how-to-fetch-element-with-name-attribute-in-react-testing-library)

Comment: @HenryWoody: thanks but i had tried the same answer and i get the same error as the author in the question.

Comment: I added another answer to that that should work for you

Comment: yes this seems to work. but still i need to use if statement. without that i get the error in question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:** While you could use the
[`container.querySelector` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986454/how-to-fetch-element-with-name-attribute-in-react-testing-library), the recommended, idiomatic way of doing it is to use RTL's built-in queries.

---

The `name` option in `*ByRole` queries refers to the *accessible name* of the element, not the value of its `name` attribute. See [What is the name option in react-testing-library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69227320/1870780) for details and references.

Given that the `input` element in your HTML doesn't have an accessible name, the only way to access it is to simply not include any option on the `getByRole` query.

```js
screen.getByRole('checkbox');
```

However, if you wanted to use the `name` option, you'd first have to add an actual accessible name to it. In your case this could be done by using the existing `label` element.

```js
<label class="switch" value="true">
    Source
    <input name="source" type="checkbox"/>
</label>
```

Which would allow you to query the `input` the way you were trying to, using the `name` option.

```js
screen.getByRole('checkbox', { name: 'Source' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```js
const elem = document.querySelector(
    `input[name="source"]`);
if (elem) {
    userEvent.click(elem);
}
```

is good because this only query for elements and return when not found any element, generally when you use get*/find* and do not find any element then rtl will throw an exception.
https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet

If you have control over that HTML the best way it will be add `data-testid` attribute and use `byTestId` https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid

Comment: This is not a good practice.
You shouldn't add new logic in unit test, because in unit test you're testing logic, so it's illogical to put `if` in unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way! The label will have `htmlFor` attribute which should match the id attribute of `input:checkbox`.

The text between opening and closing of label tag would then be the `name` of the checkbox that you can use for testing.

[image]