# React testing library: how to getByRole on custom role

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a component `<MyComponent1>` which returns:

```
return (<MyComponent2> <button aria-pressed="true"></button> </MyComponent2>);
```

Now in my unit test for `MyComponent1`, is there a way I can do `screen.getByRole('MyComponent2')`?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to specify a custom role; the roles are predefined.

That being said, if what's returned ultimately is a button then you can use `'button'` as the role as it is a valid role.

If you want to target MyComponent2 specifically you can add a test-id to it and use `getByTestId`.

```
// MyComponent1.tsx
const MyComponent1 = () => 
  <MyComponent2 data-testid="Comp2"><button aria-pressed="true"></button></MyComponent2>


// MyComponent1.spec.tsx
const myComponent2 = screen.getByTestId('Comp2');
```

Comment: thx for the reply, i just feel this is a such basic feature, wish RTL can add it.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to use a `getBy` query that effectively asserts that this button and attribute pair exists, you may be able to query by the generic button role, then assert the disabled state:

```js
expect(screen.getByRole("button")).toHaveAttribute("aria-pressed", "true");
```

or by text:

```js
expect(screen.getByText("")).toHaveAttribute("aria-pressed", "true");
```

If the attribute is the only thing that makes it unique, then you may need to resort to a non-recommended approach such as a test id or the native DOM:

```js
const {container} = render(<MyComponent1 />);
const el = container.querySelector(`button[aria-pressed="true"]`);
expect(el).toBeInTheDocument(); // with jest-dom
expect(el).not.toBeNull(); // without jest-dom; not a very clear error message
```

See also [How to fetch element with 'name' attribute in react-testing-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986454/how-to-fetch-element-with-name-attribute-in-react-testing-library/74817172#74817172) and [jest-dom #144](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/144#issuecomment-577235097).